# Implement copy: cut: and paste: in macOS app with WebView not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I am working on a project using Objective C on macOS. The project is Document-Base Application. Each window contains a WebView. I want to implement copy: cut: and paste: where the menu items for these actions should be enabled/disabled according to the object selected inside the WebView. I started a new Document-Base Application and added the following code inside AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)copy:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@ %s", self, __func__);
}
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {

    NSString *title = [menuItem title];
    NSLog(@"%@",title);
    return YES;
}
```

Before I add the WebView to the Document.xib file, everything is working fine and both copy and validateMenuItem functions are called normally. When I add WebView to the Document.xib file, these function stop working. I tried many things (such as override the WebView class) without any success. I know WebView is deprecated, but using WKWebView will cause other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebHTMLView` inside the `WebView` is the target for the `copy:` action. The `editingDelegate` of the `WebView` can intercept the `copy:` action. Implement

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)selector;
```

The `UIDelegate` of the `WebView` can validate the Copy menu item.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)webView validateUserInterfaceItem:(id<NSValidatedUserInterfaceItem>)item defaultValidation:(BOOL)defaultValidation;
```

Comment: validateUserInterfaceItem is now called inside the WebView delegate and the menu items are now enabled but, shouldPerformAction is never called

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't test very well. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but still doCommandBySelector is not called too. I tried both in WebUIDelegate and also I subclass WebView (@interface MyWebView : WebView <WebEditingDelegate>) and made MyWebView the class of WebView in Document.xib

Comment: I managed to make it work by adding [self setEditingDelegate:self]; to MyWebView. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it?